# bootstrap dropdown menu does not working in laravel project

Tags: html, css, laravel, dropdown, navbar

bootstrap dropdown menu does not appear when it is clicked in navbar. how can I solve this problem ?

```
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                   <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
          
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>
          
                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your dropdown script.

- check if jquery is loaded
- check your app.js and make jquery is loaded on it before boottrap
- run `npm run dev`
- Also check your browser console if there is no problem.

Comment: the dropdown works normally when it is out of navbar ,so what can be reason of that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

please replace with below cdn and try
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).